# Jquery .val() for input only works once

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a chat box for my game.

The user type's their chat into the input:text feild and by ither pressing Enter or clicking the button submits the chat text.

This all works, however for some reason after the first time a user submits a chat message it fails to get the text from the input field.

Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chatEnter").live('click',function(){
        var chat = $('#chatText').val();
        sendChat(chat);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chatText").keypress(function(e){
        if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13))
        {  
            var chat = $('#chatText').val();
            sendChat(chat);
            return false;
        }
        else return true;   
    });
});

function sendChat(chat)
{   
    alert(chat); //temp test alert
    $.getJSON("includes/boardUpdate.php",{chat: chat, bid: bid});
    $('#chatText').val("");
}
```

It doesn't matter if i first submit a text by clicking the button or pressing enter, all future attempts submit blank entrys until I refresh the page.

Edit: I've tried it with and without the line to clear the text box, same results both ways.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  Is there any chance that there's more than one input field with id "chatText"?

Comment: That appears to have been the problem ha ha thanks =)

Comment: couple things: don't use `live` when you have an ID; that's kind of defeating the purpose of event delegation. also, the jquery event object conforms to w3c standards, so you don't need to check for both `which` and `keyCode` in your conditional `((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13))` http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event

Comment: You should also merge all of your document.ready stuff into one...no need for two of the same thing. Also, assign chat to a variable, don't keep referencing it with a lookup. define it once, then use it all over.

Comment: if @Pointy isn't going to put that as an answer, you (@Bolt_Head) should answer it and accept it. makes it official and all.

Comment: @Pointy - Add an answer here please so I can upvote/close this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It offends The Spirits to have more than one element on the page with the same id.  Bad, weird, sometimes supernatural things happen. Often a page might seem to work for a long time, but then fail as soon as it's tweaked.

(Also thanks everybody for prodding me to provide the answer!!)